# How to use auto incremental ID in Loopback with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

Loopback has a bug with ObjectID which standard in MongoDB

so I'm trying to use a different ID in my codes

the idea is to have id attribute which has type number and (unique/ID) and be auto incremental (0,1,2 ..etc) instead of the ObjectID which is totally not working in Loopback

I searched and found this answer

```
@property({
    id: true,
    type: 'number',
    generated: true,
  })
  id: number;
```

but it looks like not working with my MongoDB collection ,
any solutions please ?

Comment: What is the bug with `ObjectID ` in Loopback ?
take a look in https://gist.github.com/drmikecrowe/5a5568930bad567d4148aad75c94de5a

Comment: @AshwanthMadhav I do not understand your codes ? where to put it in my project to help me ? is there any small documentation ? - can you explain more in answer !

Comment: @AshwanthMadhav - thanks for sharing your codes. I can see it is written for LB3 , while I'm using LB4